# When to use Dependency injection vs service locator

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependencies, service-locator

When will you use dependency injection? Is there any overwhelming benefit of using dependency injection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fowler has good comparision between the two in his [Inversion of Control Containers and the Dependency Injection pattern Heading](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). In his concluding thoughts, he says

> Dependency Injection is a useful alternative to Service Locator. When
>   building application classes the two are roughly equivalent, but I
>   think Service Locator has a slight edge due to its more
>   straightforward behavior. However if you are building classes to be
>   used in multiple applications then Dependency Injection is a better
>   choice.

You can find more view points and comparisons in [here](http://www.cookcomputing.com/blog/archives/000587.html)

For DI:

- Easier to determine what dependencies a component has - look at
  constructor.
- Component does not have dependency on Service Locator so
  there is not a problem if the component is used with a different
  framework.
- DI may make testing easier but a good Service Locator
  mechanism will make stubbing equally feasible

Against DI:

- Harder to debug and understand.
- Component cannot request extra services from injector once it had been configured.